# how can filter multilevel arrays for searching a string?

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@",@"Assets",@"TFloorAssets",@"AssetNo",strSearch];

NSArray *filteredPendingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[arrOfAllAssetsCategory filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate3]];
```

I am using above type of code for multilevel search ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [collection operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY Assets.@unionOfArrays.TFloorAssets.AssetNo contains[c] %@", strSearch]
```

Or a [subquery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411651-expressionforsubquery#discussion):

```
[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(Assets, $asset, ANY $asset.TFloorAssets.AssetNo contains[c] %@).@count > 0", strSearch]
```

Or a two subqueries:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(Assets, $asset, SUBQUERY($asset.TFloorAssets, $tFloorAsset, $tFloorAsset.AssetNo contains[c] %@).@count > 0).@count > 0", strSearch]
```

Comment: For which purpose we use @unionOfArrays or  $ ? Can you suggest me in brief or provide a link where i can read these stuffs ?

Comment: I added the links to the answer.

Comment: thnks dude @Willeke

Answer (score -1):

Use "compound predicate" like below

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                          @[predicateEventsByAsset, predicateEventsByFloorAsset ,predicateEventsByAssetNo]];
self.filteredEventsArray = [self.eventsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: This predicate does "Assets contains[c] %@ OR TFloorAssets contains[c] %@ OR AssetNo[c] contains %@". The question is how to do "ANY Assets.TFloorAssets.AssetNo contains[c] %@".